# Changing font styles google apps script

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I would like to know how can I format text to display Bold, Italic, or Underline in an email?

```
    function emailStatusUpdates() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
      var userEmail = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Username")).getValue();
      var subject = "Helpdesk Ticket #" + row;
      var body = "The status of your ticket has been updated.\n\nStatus: " +         sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Status")).getValue();
      body += " \n\nNotes:  " + sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Notes")).getValue();
      body += "\n\nResolution: " + sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Resolution")).getValue();
      body += "\n\nIssue Reported: " + sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Description")).getValue();
      MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, body, {name:"Help Desk"});
    }
```

*It is currently displaying like this:*

The status of your ticket has been updated.

Status: New

Notes:  N/A

Resolution: Test

Issue Reported: Test

*..I would like for it to display like this:*

The status of your ticket has been updated.

Status: **New**

Notes:  **N/A**

Resolution: **Test**

Issue Reported: *Test*

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the HTML option to get styles in your message.

The documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)

And a search on internet for HTML TAGS will learn you all you need to compose an HTML message.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately, I cannot seem to find the proper function. Can you assist?